# Formatting phone numbers - vba

Tags: vba, ms-access, excel, ms-access-2007

I have large data set - 10 000 records with the phone numbers:

```
Phone_N
5656666666
6676767677
6767677777
5555555555
5555567888
6666777777
```

I need to format it like:

```
Phone_N
(565) 666-6666
(222) 767-3333
(676) 777-7777
```

etc....

My data already have no spaces, "-", "/" or any other characters.

It just needed to be formatted in a proper phone format.

It would be very helpful if you could point me the right direction to start.

Comment: If you need someone to write code for you, hire a developer. Sorry, but we're not a free coding resource. `<pedantic>`Also, Stack Overflow is *not* a forum - it is a Question and Answer site. Big difference.`</pedantic>`

Comment: It would be VERY helpful if you read [ask]

Comment: In fact, you don't really need VBA for this. You can achieve this by means of a formula

Comment: right. I can do it using msaccess functions. But I thought about faster way of doing it..  well  you're VERY VERY helpful answering this question.  I'll figure it out myself then   J*****ks. Never mind.

Comment: never mind  easy done in excel !!!

Comment: oops, sorry. I should 've explain how I can do it & ask if any problems. My bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done in VBA.  You could use the following to accomplish this.

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset, TempN As String
Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT Phone_N FROM MyTableName", dbOpenDynaset)

If (rs.RecordCount <> 0) Then
  rs.MoveFirst
  Do While rs.EOF <> True
    TempN = rs.Fields("[Phone_N]").value
    rs.Edit
    rs.Fields("[Phone_N]").value = "(" & Left(TempN, 3) & ") " & _
                                   Left(Right(TempN, 7), 3) & "-" & _
                                   Right(TempN, 4)
    rs.Update
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop
End If
```

Comment: Tank you,  very interesting

Answer (score 8):

You can use the [Format Function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/format-function-HA001228839.aspx) to format `Phone_N` as you wish.  I'm not sure whether `Phone_N` is text or numeric data type, but the following `Format` example will accept either.

```vb
Phone_N = 2227673333 ' (Phone_N is numeric)
? Format(Phone_N, "(###) ###-####")
(222) 767-3333
Phone_N = "2227673333" ' (Phone_N is text)
? Format(Phone_N, "(###) ###-####")
(222) 767-3333
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a UDF (*user defined function*)

stick the below code in a standard module in VBE (*Visual Basic Editor*) <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>  right click anywhere in the Project Explorer window » Insert » Module

after formatting use ADO to UPDATE your table

```
Function FORMAT_NUMBERS(r As Range)
    FORMAT_NUMBERS = "(" & Left(r, 3) & ") " & Right(Left(r, 6), 3) & "-" & Right(r, 4)
End Function
```

example

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  That's what I was thinking

Answer (score 1):

no need to use VBA, just try Notepad++, edit your data in cloumn pattern.